# Compare two django's DateTimeField on signal

Tags: python, django

I want to use a signal to check the values of my class before it is saved in the database. I have the following function

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=A)
def on_pre_save_a(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.start_date > sender.end_date:
        raise Exception('Error with dates')
```

and my A class looks something like this

```
class A(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    scheduled_end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

But when I try to add a new A object in the admin page, an exception is raised, saying that `'>' not supported between instances of 'DeferredAttribute' and 'DeferredAttribute'`

What would the best to compare these two DateTimeField be?
And is this the best way of doing this kind of checks?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `instance` argument instead:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=A)
def on_pre_save_a(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    if instance.start_date > instance.end_date:
        raise Exception('Error with dates')
```

`sender` contain model class, while `instance` is instance of model.